# Using jQuery ajax offline on iPad

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, ipad

I am writing a site which asks a series of questions, loaded from a JSON file using jQuery Ajax.  The user runs through a series of questions, until an answer is reached which requires the loading of a new JSON file.  After some previous help from stackoverflow users, the ajax function is:

```
function loadJSON(currentkey)
{

    keytoload = "json/" + currentkey + ".json";
    $.ajax({
        url: keytoload,
        dataType: "json",
        async: true,


        error: function (request,error) {
                                        alert('Error has occurred please try again!')
                                        },
        success: function (keyloaded)   {
                                        dataset = keyloaded;
                                        askQ();//calls a function to ask a new question
                                        }
    });        
}
```

I am wanting to be able to run it on an iPad, without internet using "Offline Pages".  If I am connected to the internet, it functions fine.  If I try to read the pages offline, it fails.  When I load the page, everything is fine, but when the function is called a second time, it fails.  The exception I get is 'abort'.  It seems to work fine online in various browsers, and also offline, as a local copy on a PC.  I have tried aborting previous Ajax calls, in case these were continuing but this does not work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

**Full disclosure:** I am developer of Offline Pages Pro app.

It sounds like json files are not pre-cached, therefore any attempt to fetch them while offline would fail.

It is probably because of the way the code is organized. Offline Pages is unlikely to deduce all possible values of currentKey variable across multiple function calls. To fix this, you need to take initiative and ensure that json documents are pre-cached by adding special markup to your website.

Here's how you approach it in Offline Pages.

First, you need to create an XML document (e.g. `offline.xml`) to declare your Ajax requests. Store the document anywhere in your website. Choose any of the following options to declare your Ajax requests. Make sure to replace `yourdomain.com` with your actual hostname.

**OPTION 1** - explicitly list your json documents, each by its own `<addResource>` element:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE rules PUBLIC "-//CODIUMLABS//DTD RULES 1.0//EN" "http://codiumlabs.com/dtd/rules-1.0.dtd">
<rules domain="yourdomain.com">
    <rule>
        <addResource uri="json/key1.json" type="text/json" ajax="true" />
        <addResource uri="json/key2.json" type="text/json" ajax="true" />
        <addResource uri="json/key3.json" type="text/json" ajax="true" />
    </rule>
</rules>
```

**OPTION 2** - use sequential numbers to name your `json/key1.json`, `json/key2.json`, etc. That way you only need one `<addResource>` element:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE rules PUBLIC "-//CODIUMLABS//DTD RULES 1.0//EN" "http://codiumlabs.com/dtd/rules-1.0.dtd">
<rules domain="yourdomain.com">
    <rule>
        <addResource uri="json/key{1-20}.json" type="text/json" ajax="true" />
    </rule>
</rules>
```

**OPTION 3** - use key values stored in `data-key` attribute of `<div>` elements. This is probably the best option. If you haven't so already, put your keys in data attributes, for example: `<div data-key="key1"></div>`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE rules PUBLIC "-//CODIUMLABS//DTD RULES 1.0//EN" "http://codiumlabs.com/dtd/rules-1.0.dtd">
<rules domain="yourdomain.com">
    <rule>
        <addResource uri="json/{div[data-key]}.json" type="text/json" ajax="true" />
    </rule>
</rules>
```

Finally, add a reference to your `offline.xml` inside the `<head>` element in your page code:

```
<link rel="offlinepages-rules" type="application/vnd.offlinepages.rules+xml" href="offline.xml" />
```

If you correctly implement the above changes, Offline Pages will detect the `<link>` element, download `offline.xml`, and use your Ajax declarations to pre-cache all the json files.

Comment: Thanks for this response.  I find that Offline Pages is a really useful tool.  In my case however, I have worked out the problem was including spaces in file names.  Really simple when you realise, but it took me ages to get to this!